# Unable to Build and Package Apache Toree

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter, apache-toree

In order for EclairJS Client to talk to Apache Spark, it needs a instance of Apache Toree running and Toree must be able to connect to your Spark master.

*Prerequisites*

Java 8 update 70 or higher

*Instructions*

Download Apache Spark 2.0.0 built with Hadoop 2.7 and extract it from the archive.

Install Jupyter (`pip install jupyter` for example) and the Jupyter Kernel Gateway (`pip install jupyter-kernel-gateway`)

Download and build Apache Toree

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree

$ cd incubator-toree

$ git checkout e8ecd0623c65ad104045b1797fb27f69b8dfc23f

$ make dist
```

While Building Apache Toree, I am getting an error in the above step:

```
APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.0.0 VERSION=0.2.0.dev1-incubating IS_SNAPSHOT=true sbt toree/assembly
/bin/sh: 1: sbt: not found
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed
make: *** [target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar] Error 127
```

I am unable to figure out what to do next, can anyone can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build is failing because you need to install sbt (the Scala Build Tool). You can download it from the SBT website, here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/